# Change map to another using tileset

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm creating a game using `Phaser.js`.

It's an another 2D-retro-rpg-you've-seen-it-100000000-times and I'm using Tiled to create maps.

How am I supposed to change my map to another tileset? I'm quite confused about this. I couldn't find any definite answer in the net.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose the player reaches the end of level 1, then you want to load level 2.

You can use a variable called "currentLevel". And call the create method when you want to change levels:

```
GameState.prototype.create = function() {

    // (...)

    // Level creation
    this.level = new Level(this.game, this.currentLevel);

    // (...)
```

};

And in the level.js you can have something like this:

```
var Level = function(game, levelNumber)
{
    // LOAD TILEMAP
    Phaser.Tilemap.call(this, game, levelNumber);

    // (...) more logic to load the data from the JSON
};
```

Have I been clear enough? Hope it helps!